# Obtain acceleration plot from time and placement vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a time series vector and matrices containing placement in the x, y and z direction at respective time. How can I obtain the acceleration plot from this, in matlab?

Comment: The acceleration is the second derivative. Try something like [Approximate Derivatives with diff](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html#btw_sz6-1).

Answer (score 1):

to estimate acceleration you can use the `diff` function with argument `2` (acceleration is the second derivative):

```
% time vector
dt = 0.01;
t = (0:dt:10).';
% position coordinates
x = 2*cos(t./2);
y = 1 + exp(-t.^2);
z = sqrt(t);
% color
c = (1:numel(x)).';
% plot position
subplot(121)
h = surf([x,x],[y,y],[z,z],[c,c],...
    'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','interp','LineWidth',1);
grid on
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
title('Position(t)');
% second derivatives of x,y,z w.r.t t
dt2 = dt^2;
d2x = diff(x,2)./dt;
d2y = diff(y,2)./dt;
d2z = diff(z,2)./dt;
% color
c = (1:numel(d2x)).';
% plot derivatives
subplot(122)
h = surf([d2x,d2x],[d2y,d2y],[d2z,d2z],[c,c],...
    'FaceColor','none','EdgeColor','interp','LineWidth',1);
grid on
xlabel('x'); ylabel('y'); zlabel('z');
title('Acceleration(t)');
```

[image]